# How would I test to see if a data set is described by a specified (not calculated) 2nd order polynomial line?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, simulation, f-test

**In Short:** Given a set of data and a specified 2nd order polynomial trend line, how can I go about testing a hypothesis that the line describes the data?

I'm not asking to do a linear regression on the data to find the line of best fit with associated statistics. I want to determine if a predetermined trend line is likely to describe the data.

**In Long:** I'm attempting to verify a simulation model. The goal is to produce simulated data that follows the same characteristics of an original data set. This set is composed of introduction dates and lifetimes.

Information about the original set is limited. The lifetimes follow a Weibull distribution. Shape and scale parameters for the collective data set of lifetimes are given. However, the mean lifetime changes over time (dependent on the introduction date). This change in mean lifetime is described by a specified trend line. All we know about the trend line are its coefficients (no r-squared, F, or p -values). The distribution of introduction dates is unknown.

Currently the simulation runs like this:

- Assuming uniformly distributed introduction dates, generate dates
- Calculate a mean lifetime for introduction dates based on the given trend line
- Assume and calculate a constant standard deviation (calculated from the original collective shape and scale parameters)
- Using the constant standard deviation and the calculated mean lifetimes, solve a non-linear system of equations to find shape and scale parameters for each introduction date
- Use these shape and scale parameters to specify a Weibull distribution from which to draw a simulated lifetime.

Generating 100 simulated points in this manner and plotting them with the original trend line produces something like the following:

[image: 100 simulated data points and the original trend line.]

Given the limitations, I feel the best I can do in regards to verification is to see if the original trend line describes the data with some sort of statistical test and compute the parameters for the collective simulated lifetimes to see if the confidence intervals contain the original parameters.

I'm working mostly in R, so references to R packages, or strategies in R would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a proposed model $\mathbb E[y\vert X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2x^2$, for some $\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2$. Then you want to know if there are $\delta_0, \delta_1, \delta_2\in\mathbb R$ such that $(\beta_0 + \delta_0) + (\beta_1 + \delta_1)x + (\beta_2 + \delta_2)x^2$ provides a a better fit. Therefore, your hypothesis test, regardless of the mechanics of how you test, would be as follows.

$$
H_0: \delta_0 = \delta_1 = \delta_2 = 0\\
H_a: \text{The null hypothesis is false, and at least one of the }\delta_1\text{ are nonzero}.
$$

If any of $\delta_0$, $\delta_1$, and $\delta_2$ are nonzero, then your hypothesized values for the intercept, slope, and quadratic are not all correct.

$$
y = (\beta_0 + \delta_0) + (\beta_1 + \delta_1)x + (\beta_2 + \delta_2)x^2 + \epsilon
\\\bigg\Updownarrow\\
y - \beta_0 - \beta_1x-\beta_2x^2 = \delta_0 + \delta_1x+\delta_2x^2 + \epsilon
$$

Therefore, I would say to treat $y - \beta_0 - \beta_1x-\beta_2x^2$ as your dependent variable and fit a usual regression on the $x$ variable and its square.$^{\dagger}$. I would then do a test of nested linear models with this model containing a regression of this new $y$ on nothing, not even an intercept. After all, if the original coefficients are correct, there should be no difference.

An F-test of nested linear models would be a way to test this.

A quick simulation suggests that this is at least not a terrible way to proceed. The result of this simulation is that the p-values are more-or-less distributed $U(0,1)$ when the correct coefficients are subtracted (to form `y_new` in the language of this code), yet the test has considerable power to reject when the wrong coefficients are subtracted, the latter of which corresponds to the situation where the original coefficients you have assumed are not correct.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
R <- 10000
x <- runif(N)
Ey <- 2 + 2*x + 2*x^2
ps1 <- ps2 <- rep(NA, R)
for(i in 1:R){
  
  # Add some noise to the conditional expected value of y
  #
  y <- Ey + rnorm(N)
  
  # Do the subtraction
  #
  y_new <- y - 2 - 2*x - 2*x^2
  
  # Regress using the new y-variable
  #
  L1 <- lm(y_new ~ x + I(x^2))
  
  # Now regress on nothing
  #
  L0 <- lm(y_new ~ 0)
  
  # Do the F-test of nested models 
  #
  f_test <- anova(L1, L0)
  
  # Save the p-value from the overall F-test
  #
  ps1[i] <- f_test$`Pr(>F)`[2]
  
  # Now do it but assume the wrong parameters to subtract
  
  # Do the subtraction
  #
  y_new <- y - 1.9 - (2.1)*x - (1.7)*x^2
  
  # Regress using the new y-variable
  #
  L1 <- lm(y_new ~ x + I(x^2))
  
  # Now regress on nothing
  #
  L0 <- lm(y_new ~ 0)
  
  # Do the F-test of nested models 
  #
  f_test <- anova(L1, L0)
  
  # Save the p-value from the overall F-test
  #
  ps2[i] <- f_test$`Pr(>F)`[2]
  
}

d1 <- data.frame(
  pvalue = c(ps1, ps2),
  CDF = ecdf(ps1)(c(ps1, ps2)),
  Null = "True"
)
d2 <- data.frame(
  pvalue = c(ps1, ps2),
  CDF = ecdf(ps2)(c(ps1, ps2)),
  Null = "False"
)
d <- rbind(d1, d2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = pvalue, y = CDF, col = Null)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image: p-value CDFs]

$^{\dagger}$ One thought could be to use orthogonal polynomials for better numerical stability. In that case, I would use the orthogonal polynomials from the beginning.

Comment: If you want to show that the original coefficients are correct or correct within some tolerance that you define as "close enough", that is a separate question and more difficult. I believe it warrants its own post.